# Own structure for pages and posts in search results

Tags: wordpress, search, post

It's a post info. I tried to make something, but no results.

Here's what I made:

If in search results is displaying post, put this code in its info:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>

      <span itemprop="author">
        <span itemprop="name">
          <?php the_author() ?>
        </span>
      </span>, in category «<?php the_category(', ') ?>», 
  <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php the_time('c'); ?>">
  <?php the_time('F j, Y') ?>
  </time>
```

Else (if in search results is displaying page):

```
        <?php else : ?>

Page, updated at: <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="<?php the_modified_time('c'); ?>">
    <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?>
      </time>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Instead of this it do "Else" code for all posts and pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>`

use

`<?php if ( get_post_type() == 'post' ) : ?>`

or

`<?php if ( get_post_type() != 'page' ) : ?>`

(depending on the logic you want to have)

[is_single()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) returns `true` when a post's single page is displayed (it will return `false` inside a search loop).